# Parse unknown JSON path in TSQL with openjson and/or json_value

Tags: json, t-sql

I have a incoming data structure that looks like this:

```
declare @json nvarchar(max) = '{
    "action": "edit",
    "data": {
        "2077-09-02": {
            "Description": "some stuff",
            "EffectDate": "2077-1-1"
        }
    }
}';
```

To give you a long story short, I think TSQL hates this json structure, because no matter what I have tried, I can't get to any values other than "action".

The {data} object contains another object, {2077-09-02}.  "2077-09-02" will **always be different**.  I can't rely on what that date will be.

This works:

```
select json_value(@json, '$.action');
```

**None** of this works when trying to get to the other values.

```
select json_value(@json, '$.data');  --returns null

select json_value(@json, '$.data[0]'); --returns null

select json_value(@json, 'lax $.data.[2077-09-02].Description');
--JSON path is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '[' is found at position 11.

select json_value(@json, 'lax $.data.2077-09-02.Description');
--JSON path is not properly formatted. Unexpected character '2' is found at position 11.
```

How do I get to the other values?  Is the JSON not perfect enough for TSQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is never a good idea to use the declarative part of a text based container as data. The `"2077-09-02"` is a valid json key, but hard to query.

You can try this:

```
declare @json nvarchar(max) = '{
    "action": "edit",
    "data": {
        "2077-09-02": {
            "Description": "some stuff",
            "EffectDate": "2077-1-1"
        }
    }
}';

SELECT A.[action]
      ,B.[key] AS DateValue
      ,C.*
FROM OPENJSON(@json)
WITH([action] NVARCHAR(100)
    ,[data]   NVARCHAR(MAX) AS JSON) A
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(A.[data]) B 
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(B.[value]) 
WITH (Description NVARCHAR(100)
     ,EffectDate DATE) C;
```

The result

```
action  DateValue   Description EffectDate
edit    2077-09-02  some stuff  2077-01-01
```

The idea:

- The first `OPENJSON` will return the `action` and the `data`.
- I use a `WITH` clause to tell the engine, that `action` is a simple value, while `data` is nested JSON
- The next `OPENJSON` dives into `data`
- We can now use `B.[key]` to get the json key's value
- Now we need another `OPENJSON` to dive into the columns *within* `data`.

However: If this JSON is under your control I'd suggest to change its structure.

Comment: this is some high-level SQL, my friend, thank you!!!  The structure you see is from DataTable's Editor. The {data: ""} object *could* contain multiple objects, which represent a row that's being modified; the hard-to-query key represents the row actively being modified.  It's the HTML id of the row, AND the primary key in the table.  Long Story Short, YES, I can manually manipulate the structure and make it FLAT --- but with this, you have taught me something new, and now I can leave the original structure intact if I choose to do so, thus saving extra lines of JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Use double quotes instead of `[]`. [JSON Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-path-expressions-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017) uses JavaScript's conventions where a string is surrounded by double quotes. The documentation's example contains this path `$."first name"`.

In this case :

```
select json_value(@json,'$.data."2077-09-02".Description');
```

Returns :

```
some stuff
```

As for the other calls, [JSON_VALUE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) can only return scalar values, not objects. You need to use [JSON_QUERY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/json-query-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to extract JSON objects, eg :

```
select json_query(@json,'$.data."2077-09-02"');
```

Returns :

```
{
    "Description": "some stuff",
    "EffectDate": "2077-1-1"          
}
```

Comment: Oh man, that's great!  How do I reference the path to the object if I don't know what the root date will be?